# Check first 7 charactors of a field has duplicate in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to update based on the first 7 characters of a field.

For example:
I have filed named *rds* with multiple values starting from "10-1111". If there are more than one value I need to update another field named "multiorders" with "yes" if there is only a single value i need to update "multiorders" with "no"

```
rds | multiorders
10-1111-1332     |      yes
10-1111-4322     |      yes
10-1111-8779     |      yes
11-3224-4444     |      no
12-4567-3322     |      no
16-3354-6645     |      no
17-3344-7777     |      yes
17-3344-1212     |      yes
```

it should only check the first 7 charactor and update the multiorders with yes or no

Comment: which dbms ? `mysql` or `sql server` ?

Comment: sqlserver and i cant add sample in tabular format for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try query like this:

```
update y 
set y.multiorders='yes' 
from yourtable y where left(y.rds,7) in (select left(rds,7) as rds from yourtable group by left(rds, 7) having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: am sorry ask i am pretty new to sql server what is ;with means

Comment: i just used common table expressions, you can use that with subqueries as well...

Comment: can you show me one without common table expressions

Comment: updated teh query without common table expressions.. check this with your query

Answer (score 1):

Hi Rinu,
 You can use below query,

```
MERGE INTO table_name T1
USING 
    (SELECT SUBSTR(rds,1,7) AS RDS, COUNT(*) FROM table_name 
     GROUP BY RDS HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)T2
ON
T2.RDS = SUBSTR(T1.RDS,1,7)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET
    multiorders='YES'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET
    multiorders='NO';
```

> Explination

- You can use MERGE function to update you table for your requirement
- Use same table name in place of **table_name**
- Have selected the count of rds column, if the count of that colum is greater than 1, i.e, it has duplicates for first 7 characters
- 7 characters are selected using substring function, you can also substr function in case of oracle database
  Hope you got what you need, any issues feel free to ask